# TFS2017 Manual Build not using latest source version

Tags: tfs

We've just recently updated from TFS2015 to TFS2017 Update 1. The upgrade process went smoothly with no issues. Everything was looking fine until we manually queued one of our builds.

[image]

In 2015, when we manually queued a build, we would get a popup window specifying which queue we wanted it to build on, and allowing you to specify a specific changeset source version. Leaving the source version blank would make it build the latest changeset from it's source.

The issue we're seeing is it seems to be picking an older changeset when we leave the source version blank, and is no longer defaulting to the latest version. Has anyone experienced this problem? and does anyone know how we fix this?

CI Builds will correctly build the latest version. It's only doing it on manually queued builds.

It feels like there's a config value somewhere which has a default changeset to use.

Comment: Can you specify the latest Source version (changeset) to build? Does the new build definition have the same issue? Just create a new definition to try it.

Comment: If I specify the build, it has no problems at all. It's just when I leave it blank. In TFS2015, we were able to leave it blank and it would just grab the latest changeset.

Comment: Are you perhaps building a branch for which the older changeset is the most recent?

Comment: Can you share the build logs for Get Sources step?

Answer (score 0):

First please check if the latest changeset is lost. If it's exist, then try following below steps to check if it works:

1. Modify your definition : In Repository set **Clean** to **True**,
   **Clean option to Sources** (try to set **Source Directory** if that not work)
2. Also enable **Clean** option for your build solution task

If that still not work, you can try to create new Collection >  new team project  > Check in files several time > Check the issue again.
[image]

Comment: @ICTech Any update for this? have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this for a while, and I have finally worked this out.

**Background:** We have a gated build set up, and then a different build that we can queue up to prepare a release. We would check in a Gated build, and then immediately queue up the other build, on the expectation that the Gated build will complete successfully, causing those changes to be checked-in; and the second build that we had "queued" would be done after that.

**Cause:** As you have indicated in the question, we leave the "Source Version" blank, expecting it to use the latest build at the point where the build starts; but that isn't what it does. It makes a note of what the latest changeset is at the point where you **queue** the build.

**Proof:** In the build log, look at the "Get Sources" step, you will find a value looking like this:

```
2018-10-04T09:44:06.6339435Z ##[command]tf vc get /version:95476 /recursive /overwrite "C:\Agents\Agent EA3 1\_work\34\s" /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
```

The `/version:95476` was the latest changeset at the point where I queued the build, **not** the latest at the point where the build started.

**Solution 1** The solution is to enter [the value "T"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=vsts#use-a-versionspec-argument-to-specify-affected-versions-of-items) into the "Source Version" to explicitly say that you want the latest version (even though I would have expected that to be the default behaviour).

*@Microsoft: this is a misleading default value, given that I am "queueing" a build to happen in the future, please make this configurable (either for a build or a build server) so we can make it work the sensible way.*

**Solution 2** (only do this if you *always* want it to use the latest version, regardless of what is entered as the "Source Version")
Add a new "Command Line" Task in the build process after "Get sources". Set the display name to be `Force get latest, regardless of what version was queued`, Tool should be `tf` and arguments should be `vc get /version:T /recursive /overwrite "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" /noprompt`

Comment: So trying solution 1 STILL does not give us the latest change set version.

I have tried solution 2, and I am getting this error: "tf is not a recognized internal or external command"

Am I missing something? Help would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: Check the logs for the get sources step: What does it say immediately after `tf vc get /version:`? And what makes you think it's not the latest version? The "tf is not recognised" means it's not finding `tf.exe`, but if your log has what I've shown in my answer then it's on the path, so it will work for this command because it works for get sources. These solutions both work for me. Perhaps you need to ask a separate question?

Comment: Directly after /version: is a change set number that is not in fact the latest change set. I know this because I can see change sets in the source control explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: do you have anything for the advanced settings or control options in the command line task?

Comment: With solution 1 it should say `/version:T`, if you give that as the source version, that's how it's designed to work. For solution 2 I'm not using *anything* other than the 3 values I gave on a "Command Line" task.